# error while installing tkinter in python on windows 10

Tags: windows, tkinter, installation

```
C:\Users\acer\Desktop\python\project>pip install tkinter
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can't install tkinter using pip.  It should be installed when installing Python.

Answer (score 2):

From the Python (3.1>) prompt, enter these two commands:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter._test()
```

to check the installation of tkinter.

More info here:  https://tkdocs.com/